# Slow query on Access database over LAN

Tags: ms-access, vb6, ado

I use the typical ADO Jet OLE 4.0 connection with VB6. For example:

```
Set CONN = New ADODB.Connection
With CONN
    .Open _
            "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" & _
            "Data Source=C:\DATABASE\QA1.mdb;" & _
            "Jet OLEDB:Engine Type=4;"
    .Properties("Jet OLEDB:Max Locks Per File") = 25000000
End With
```

And I open the recordset with:

```
Set RSTX = New ADODB.Recordset
RSTX.CursorLocation = adUseClient
SQL = "SELECT ecc, ecc1, ecc2 from tab1 where ecc='2'"
RSTX.Open SQL, CNT, adOpenStatic, adLockReadOnly, adCmdText
```

But the query is very very very slow. Possibly I need to add cursor type or completely completly change my strategy. Note: All fields for WHERE clause are indexed.

Comment: This is not valid SQL.  "SELECT ecc where ecc"

Comment: @SQLDBA it would if ecc is boolean

Comment: @mike are you sure? `SELECT cbool(1) where cbool(1)` doesn't work in Access for me.

Comment: That is good to know Mike.  SELECT ecc FROM Table1 WHERE ecc; does work if ecc is bool.  But still need a table in SO example.

Comment: @user1579247 What are you trying to achieve with this SQL? Does this actually run?

Comment: @SQLDAB good point, totally missed that.  user1579247 try adding a FROM clause to your sql

Comment: I wonder whether `ecc` is Internet Pidgin English for `etc.` i.e. not literal code but "there is stuff here?"

Comment: @user1579247  You mention that you are opening this database on the LAN in your title. However, the MDB file is accessed from the C:\DATABASE folder. Is the 'tab1' table actually attached to a remote database? Otherwise your reference to LAN makes no sense.